# self.view removeFromSuperview crashes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view

i hope this is my last question for a while, I open a xib file via:

```
Results1 *myView1 = [[Results1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"Results1" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:myView1.view];
```

I have a button on the second xib file:

```
-(IBAction)Button1:(id)sender
{

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

It crashes every time:

```
0xecf09b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi
```

I have the views linked

I am not sure if this is the problem:

```
@interface TestTypingToolViewController ()

{
    NSString *iResults1;
    NSString *iResults2;
    NSString *iResults3;
    NSString *iResults4;
    NSString *iResults5;
    NSString *Segment;
    NSDictionary *ResultsData;
}

@end
```

Thanks for all your help, everyone!

Comment: are you using ARC? what is the kind of error that causes the crash and on which line of your code (not the `movl`, too low level) does it occur? this info is available on the output console...

Comment: I dont know what ARC is but I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xa0686703)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is I needed to turn off Automatic Reference Counting and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have got some issue with zombies, i.e., some object that is deallocated at some point but you try to access through some (dangling) reference. You could get more info about it by [enabling zombies detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode).

Actually, my guess is that you could fix this by storing `Results1 *myView1` in a property of your class. Indeed, in your code, what happens is the `myView1.view` is retained by `self.view`; while `myView1` is stored in a local variable, so the object (under ARC) should be deallocated when the variable is not used anymore. You have a mismatch here between the lifetimes of the two objects and this could lead to the crash.

Comment: So something like this in the .h file?
    @property (nonatomic,retain) Results1 *myView1
sorry I am new to objective c

Comment: With Zombie Detection on the error now is:
calll  0x14fe884                 ; symbol stub for: getpid
EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT, subcode=0x0

Comment: `@property (nonatomic,retain) Results1 *myView1` is what I though of (or `@property (nonatomic,strong) Results1 *myView1` if you using ARC)... don't forget to call `release` in your class `dealloc` (in the non-ARC case; if using ARC/strong, no release is required).

Answer (score -2):

ClassName.h

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *myView1;`

ClassName.m

```
@synthersize myView1;
```

// in -(void)viewDidLoad

```
self.myView1 = [[Result1 alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:self.myView1.view];
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in words, not only code, so that everyone can understand. Also, since you are answering an old question, how does your answer differ from the other answers?